# Delete all row from all table from MYSQL DB with some ID clause

Tags: mysql, delete-row

Is it possible to delete all rows from all tables in **MYSQL** DB with `some id = '123'`.

Actually I needed this because there is lots of **junk data** in others table but in main table rows are **deleted**, I have the IDs.

Now the new logic is implemented in the right way but I have to delete previous rows. Is it possible in a single `MYSQL` query?

There is no **DBA** level cascading relationship.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? If that that is a foreign key on another table and cascade is enabled then the secondary record will also be deleted.

Comment: yes i need that, i have no problem with that, first i will tested with then will applying that

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you output based on my database which has multiple tables having column Id. So replace my db 'djangogirls' with your-database-name.

### SQL Query (Replace djangogirls with your database name)

```
SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',TABLE_NAME," WHERE Id = '1';") FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'djangogirls'
AND COLUMN_NAME ='Id';
```

The output for above will be a list of sql delete statement which you can copy paste and simply run it.

### Output

```
DELETE FROM auth_group WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM auth_group_permissions WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM auth_permission WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM auth_user_groups WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM auth_user_user_permissions WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM blog_post WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM django_admin_log WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM django_content_type WHERE Id = '1';
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE Id = '1';
```

Again make sure that you know exactly what you are doing. Better make backup using `mysqldump -u root -p yourdb > yourdb.sql` command.